# iCloud в приложении на реальном устройстве

Tags: xcode, swift

Не работает *iCloud* в приложении на РЕАЛЬНОМ УСТРОЙСТВЕ.

Когда тестирую в симуляторе, то все отлично работает.

На `developer.apple.com` смотрел *id* приложения, там *iCloud* включен. Как только заливаю приложение на *itunes connect* и приглашаю людей в *testflight*, то ничего не работает.

Может, нужно что-то на сайте включить? Или в телефоне настройки какие? А может на developer.apple.com что-то еще нужно?